# Undefined local variable or method "product"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create an *on show* page but my code is not working.

Models look like -> User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :plan
  has_one :profile
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
      self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
      save!
    end
  end
end
```

Product model->

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    has_one :opsystem, class_name: "Opsystem",
                        foreign_key: "opsystem_id"
    validates_presence_of :name, :price
    validates_numericality_of :price

    attr_accessor :name
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    def opsystem

    end
end
```

Comment model ->

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :coment, :product_id, :user_id
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Products controller ->

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @products = Product.all
        @admin_user = User.find(3)
    end

    def show
        @products = Product.all
        @admin_user = User.find(3)
        @opsystems = Opsystem.all
        # users = User.where(name: 'Oscar')
        # users.new.name # => 'Oscar'
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
        @product_os = @product.opsystem_id
        @opsystem = Opsystem.find(@product_os)
        @comment = Comment.new
        @comment.user = current_user

        # @operatingsystems = Opsystem.find_by(id: @pr )
    end

    def new
      @admin_user = User.find(3)
      @opsystems = Opsystem.all
        if current_user == @admin_user
            @product = Product.new
        else
             redirect_to root_url
        end

    end

     # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
       @admin_user = User.find(3)
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @opsystems = Opsystem.all

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :image, :review, :processor, :ram_rom, :battery, :review, :display, :video, :camera, :opsystem_id )
    end
end
```

Comments controller->

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
          @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
          @comment = @product.comments.build(params[:comment])
          @comment.user = current_user
        if @comment.save
            redirect_to @product, notice: "Comment was created."
        else
            render :new
        end
    end
end
```

In `products/show.html.erb`, from product, I've inserted this form:

```
<div class="comment-wrapper">
          <ul class="comments">
              <%= render 'comments/comments' %>
              <li>
                <div class="comment-box-wrapper">
                  <%= form_for [@product, Comment.new], :remote => true do |f| %>
                    <div class="comment-textarea">
                      <%= f.text_area :coment %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                      <%= f.submit "Comment", :class => "btn btn-small pull-right" %>
                    </div>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

comments/_comments.html.erb contain ->

```
<% @product.comments.each do |comment| %>
 <li>
  <div class="comment-inner-wrapper">
    <div class="comment-controls">
     <% if comment.user == current_user %>          
       <%= link_to [@product, comment], :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" do  %>
        <i class="icon-trash"></i>
       <% end %>
     <% end %>
   </div>
   <div class="comment-author-pic">
    <%= link_to comment.user do %>
      <%= image_tag comment.user.image.url(:thumb) %>
    <% end %>
   </div>
   <div class="comment-author">
    <%= link_to comment.user.username, comment.user %>
   </div>
   <div class="comment-content">
     <p><%= comment.content %></p>
   </div>
 </div>
</li>
<% end %>
```

[image]

I'm a beginner with this technology and I'm afraid I might be making some mistake while creating the table:

```
create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text    "coment"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "product_id"
  end
 create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.float   "price"
    t.text    "review"
    t.string  "display"
    t.string  "processor"
    t.string  "ram_rom"
    t.string  "battery"
    t.string  "camera"
    t.string  "video"
    t.string  "image"
    t.integer "opsystem_id"
  end
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "plan_id"
    t.string   "stripe_customer_token"
    t.integer  "comment_id"
  end
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - you don't need backticks (```) for indented code blocks. Only to create inline blocks with a fixed font `like this`.

Answer (score 3):

The `product` variable isn't defined in your show view. Instead you can use `@project` which you've defined in your controller and will be passed to your view by Rails.

Comment: When i try to post comment i've get jquery.js?body=1:9632 POST https://my-blog-maikldan.c9users.io/comments 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with your comment `form_for` call.  Here's what it should look like:

```
<%= form_for [@product, Comment.new], url: new_comment_path(@product), :remote => true, html: { method: :post } do |f| %>
```

Changes made:

- Change form_for target to `url: new_comment_path(@product, Comment.new)`
- Use @product instead of product
- Add `html: { method: :post }` option

This is closer to what you need to make your comments work.  There are the changes explained:

The `:url` option allows you to specify which url endpoint the form will be sent to.  The jQuery error that you reported indicates that the form was targeting the `/comments` path, when you actually wanted it to target the `/comments/new` path.  Using the route helper for a new comment, you get `new_comment_path(@product)` as the proper endpoint.

The `@product` model object is used as it's passed from the controller to the view.  This was likely just a typo.

The `:html` option allows you to provide additional options to the HTML generation of the form element.  In this case, we're telling Rails to generate a `POST` form, since Rails had concluded that this was a `GET` form.  This will allow the form submit to be `POST`ed to your `/comments/new` controller, as it should be.

One additional note: you've got a typo in `:coment', used in your Comments migration, the Comment model, and in your form.  If this is early in your project, you'll want to correct that, as it becomes tedious to deal with misspelled field names later.

---

#### UPDATE

In `products/show.html.erb` remove `Comment.new` from the `form_for` arguments, like this:

```
<%= form_for @product, url: new_comment_path(@product), :remote => true, html: { method: :post } do |f| %>
```

When creating a new model object, the object should not be included in the path.

Comment: i change form and rename column in comments to text_comment and i get this error 
POST https://my-blog-maikldan.c9users.io/comments/new.1 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please show the routes for Product, Users, and Comments

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Please see the update at the end.